# Ubuntu 18.04 "sudo apt-get install python2" results in "E: Unable to locate package python2"

Tags: python-2.x

In preparation for supporting a Python 2 legacy application I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.5, which includes Python 3 but not Python 2.  Pretty much every Python 2 install tutorial website shows the following command for installing Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python2
```

Upon which I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python2
```

Some sites list these commands first so I tried these as well:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2
```

This gives the same results as above.

I setup Ubuntu 20.04 on a different computer and installed Python 2 about a month ago and I could swear I used the same commands and at that time it worked.  I also remember something about Python 2 being decommissioned at the end of January 2021 (which just passed).

Was the Python 2 pip package taken down?  Is there some way I can verify this?  If so, is there some special curl command that can still download Python 2 or a website I can download it from?

Comment: the package for 18.04 is `python` or `python2.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the Ubuntu packages, it seems that for some odd reason for Ubuntu 20.04 the name of the Python 2 package is `python2` but for Ubuntu 18.04 there is no package named `python2`.  It seems that for Ubuntu 18.04 by running:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

This installs both pip for Python 2 and Python 2 itself, so this seems to be the best option

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to install with

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

wich is the latest version of python 2.